# Implementing API for captcha while calling a public URL?

Tags: rest, captcha, api-design

I am trying to implement REST API for a form(Let's say booking a ticket). That is a public URL . **In Web the public URLs are protected with Captcha to avoid spammers**. So do I need to implement an REST API for providing a captcha and get back the captcha input along with the other inputs while adding details to the form ??

Thanks In Advance

Comment: Do people need to sign up and use an API key to call your REST service or can anyone hit it?  Probably not a good idea to captcha the API, but at the very least rate limit it per IP address to prevent abuse.

Comment: @drew010 thanks for the update but any one can access the api the user don't need to signup to access the API . May i know why its not a good idea ..

Comment: REST API's are generally stateless and requiring a CAPTCHA breaks that promise.  I'd either require a (free) signup to generate a key that you can use to track users (and ban violators) or implement rate limiting per IP address instead of a captcha.